# Analysis Of Wheel Speed Sensor using Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency, simulink

Looking for suggestions and guidance.

I have a Hall Effect, Wheel Speed sensor(*I have never worked with Wheel Speed Sensors in the past* ), the data of which i can read using Matlab. I need suggestions as to which approach is better and why?

Approach 1: Using the Matlab -> Microcontroller -> Timer Unit->Caluculate the Frequency Change -> Wheel Speed

OR

Appraoch 2: Using Matlab -> Discretization Algorithm -> Frequency -> Wheel Speed

As for approach 2, what are merits for different algorithms? How to select one?

Thanks for any input.

And, Before Downvoting please tell me my mistake so i can improve my question.

Comment: IMHO: When undertaking a task like this from scratch, wouldn't the *best* approach be the one that you can implement?

Comment: @Schorsch: I can implement Approach 1, which is simple and have done the same before with different persepective (detection of frequency). But due to hardware and functional limitations i am also inclined to consider the second approach. its a matter of a judgement call. thanks for your comment!